# How to structure urls with backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing

I'm building a ticketing system website in [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/). I now need to get a collection of messages belonging to one ticket. At first I thought of the obvious route `'/ticket/:id'`. Unfortunately, this already returns the ticket itself (creation date and which supporter was assigned to it). For this reason I need a different route.

A second logical option would be `'/message/:id'`, but of course this refers to the individual message of a certain id.

So my question is: which route or url would you think is logical (keeping in mind the Backbonejs way of doing things) for getting all messages belonging to a certain ticket id? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to model a collection of messages belongs to a ticket, you should use:

/tickets/:id/messages/